# php mailer is not working with some emails

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using php mailer to send emails using php, it was working fine. for some reason today my client called and told me that it doesen't work with some emails!

i don't know what is the reaoson why it works for some emails and it doesn't for some!

here is my code:

```
 <?php


include("config.php");
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

     function  send_mail($email,$message,$subject)
        {    


            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet='UTF-8';
            $mail->From = "myEmail@wissamapps.esy.es";
$mail->FromName = "DRIVER";

//To address and name
//$mail->addAddress("recepient1@example.com", "Recepient Name");
$mail->addAddress($email); //Recipient name is optional

//Address to which recipient will reply
$mail->addReplyTo("myEmail@wissamapps.esy.es", "Reply");

//CC and BCC
//$mail->addCC("cc@example.com");

//Send HTML or Plain Text email
$mail->isHTML(false);
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 4;
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $message;
//$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    return  $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
echo 'email is sent correctly';
    return '1';

}
        }

     function  generateRandomCode($length, $keyspace = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
{
    $str = '';
    $max = mb_strlen($keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        $str .= $keyspace[mt_rand(0, $max)];
    }
    return $str;
}

send_mail('mah.moh.mak.9@gmail.com',"test","test");

?>
```

this email is one of the emails doesn't recieve my emails, I checked the spam and everything but its not there, i also got some advice on changing from "mah.moh.mak.9@gmail.com" to 'mah.moh.mak.9@gmail.com' , but still the result is the same.

also tried adding

> $mail->CharSet='UTF-8';

also worth mentioning that:
$mail->send() is true 
but still not working, can you advise what the problem is ?

Comment: Read [here](http://www.slate.com/blogs/future_tense/2013/08/01/dots_in_gmail_addresses_what_happens_if_you_leave_out_the_period.html) for the dots. Don't know if it's helpful but a good to know thing.

Comment: Just because you've successfully submitted a message to your local mail server (what you're doing) doesn't mean it will be delivered. You need to check your mail server logs to see what happens to your messages. You only get SMTP debug output if you're using SMTP. It would help if you read [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I tried the email with dots and without dots but still it didn't send..

Comment: @Synchro actually there is no log for my mail local server, I did try sending a normal email using the local mail server interface (not PHPMailer) and the thing is, its working fine and I am able to receive the message. any more suggestions ?

Comment: Because PHPMailer is returning true from `send()`, it means the problem is in your mail server, not your code. If your mail server isn't logging, enable it.